# Why did my array values get updated to random values?

Tags: c++, arrays, dev-c++

I have a grid with 2 rows and 3 columns. I do an operation where I do not update any element of the grid, rather just access it. Somehow, my grid has been updated with random values

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

int grid[2][3]{{1,3,5},
                {2,4,-10}};
int row{sizeof(sizeof(grid)/sizeof(grid[0]))};
int col{sizeof(grid[0])/sizeof(int)};
int dp[3][4]{};
for(auto &y:grid){
    for(auto x:y){
        cout<<x<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
for(int i{1};i<=row;i++){
    for(int j{1};j<=col;j++){
        dp[i][j]=grid[i-1][j-1]+max(dp[i][j-1],dp[i-1][j]);
    }
}
cout<<"++++++++++++++++++++++++"<<endl;
for(auto &y:grid){
    for(auto x:y){
        cout<<x<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
}
```

output:

```
1       3       5  
2       4       -10  
++++++++++++++++++++++++  
1       4       8  
7       4       3
```

When I run this code on online IDE like [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh) I am not getting the problem. But I'm using devC++ and maybe this is some specific issue with devC++ rather than my code.

Comment: When I run your example I see the same printed values for both. Is this a complete example?

Comment: yes all this is in main function

Comment: @luxun yes you're right. problem might be with devC++

Comment: also when I'm running your code on www.onlinegdb.com the values stays the same but I'm getting a segmentation fault

Comment: @yaodav, I get it. I miscalculated rows. my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of `row` is incorrect:

```
int row{sizeof(sizeof(grid)/sizeof(grid[0]))};
```

this gives the value of `8` (on my machine, but in general it gives the size of an `int`). You have an extra `sizeof` in there. This means you are invoking undefined behavior in your second loop, by indexing out of bounds.

Instead do:

```
int row{sizeof(grid)/sizeof(grid[0])};
```

which gives `2` as needed.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/t24QzH).